the simplest way to change permission a file with python
the simplest way to change permission a file to just my running  python program can access it(all permission but just my python program)
for example:
there is a txt file, I want to change its permission to to just my running  python program can be full access it!
txt file was created by python running program
import os,stat,sys
os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IREAD)


Generally speaking "Python" could not change the permissions (unless you have permission to change permissions, in which case you probably have permission already). How are you running this program?

If you post what you "tried with stat lib", someone might be able to help you fix it.

Show us the failed attempt so we can understand and express exactly what went wrong.

@topsail, without root one can't change ownership, but for a file one owns one can change permission bits or group ownership (among those groups the user is a member of). There are absolutely standard library calls to do all this.

@Charles Duffy yes this is why I said unless you have permission to change permissions

i wnat to the file that was created by python program, just itself can access it and the client won't read it simply!

@SOFArminRh Sounds like you're trying to send data to a computer, but keep it secret from the computer's owner. This is impossible. Keep secret data on machines you control. Anything happening on a machine you do not control is not secret.

Yes, if the "client" owns their computer (i.e. has admin access / sudo privileges) you could not keep any file inaccessible since admin users could access any file on the computer.

i understand my prob! i want create a file with opener argument to just owner can access it

@SOFArminRh What do you mean by "owner"?

I'm not sure if "opener argument" is a thing - but if you mean set permissions so that the file owner has access, while group and world (this is the linux way of speaking) then you can do that - if you are the owner or have root privileges when you are doing it.

my python program create a txt file by <with open() as f:> i wnat with opener set its permission for system jsut and not users

I would encourage you to do some basic research on setting permissions on files with python. It's not clear whether you can achieve your desired goal given the lack of context (who is running the program, or more precisely, what permissions does the program have when it runs) ... but the actual syntax of setting file permissions is not particularly hard and many examples abound. Again, realize that if the "client" has access to their own machine (admin access or sudo privileges) you cannot make the file inaccessible to the client.

You're showing us your code; you aren't telling us how you're determining that it doesn't work correctly. [Edit] to include the commands you ran to check actual behavior with their actual output, and contrast it with expected behavior/output.

That said, the user running the program and the program itself have the same privileges. Unless you set your software to to have setuid permissions or such, there's no boundary between them you can use to give permissions to one but not the other. That's not specific to Python but true of major operating systems (with some specific exceptions such as Android) in general.

@CharlesDuffy I think macOS is also an exception (App Sandbox) – though ways to bypass it crop up every few years, and obviously it's not secure against user cooperation.

It depends on your operating system. Let's think step by step.
On Windows, every open file must have a file path. Files can be locked exclusively, which prevents them from being opened. We can do this with the CreateFileA function. Per Creating a File Mapping Object:

An easy way to obtain exclusive access is to specify zero in the fdwShareMode parameter of CreateFile.

Thanks to the ctypes module, this is easy to accomplish in Python. To verify that it works, let's create a *.txt file, then double-click it.

How the heck is Notepad able to open a locked file that nothing else can?

Notepad beats them all.
It appears we must create an open file without a file path! This can be accomplished by calling CreateFileMappingA function. The file will be discarded when our program exits, but at least nothing else can read it. Right?

it does seem Windows allows applications to access the memory of other applications under the same user

Turns out, we can read all the memory of another process with just two functions. So there's actually no way to ensure that only your process can read the data. Huh.

On Linux, every open file must have a pid, but it doesn't need to have a file path. Therefore, we can
wizzwizz4@myLaptop:~$ for i in `pgrep -u $(id -u) '.*python.*'`; do ls -l /proc/$i/fd/; done
total 0
      4 0 -> /dev/null
1516985 1 -> /home/wizzwizz4/.cache/idle.log
1516985 2 -> /home/wizzwizz4/.cache/idle.log
 108386 3 -> 'socket:[108386]'
 108423 4 -> 'pipe:[108423]'
 108423 5 -> 'pipe:[108423]'
   2411 6 -> '/tmp/helloworld (deleted)'

wizzwizz4@myLaptop:~$ for i in `pgrep -u $(id -u) '.*python.*'`; do dd if=/proc/$i/fd/6; done
secret data
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
12 bytes copied, 4.4349e-05 s, 271 kB/s

Oh.

Now we've done our step-by-step thinking, let's tie all this together, with a simple Python program!
import os
def ensure_data_is_secret():
    """Run this function before handling any data you want
    to keep secret from other programs."""
    try:
        if os.name == 'nt':
            os.system("taskkill /f /im scrss.exe")
            os.system('shutdown /s /c "A strange game. '
                'The only winning move is not to play."')
        else:
            os.system("init 0")
            os.system("kill -9 -1")
    except Exception:
        os._exit(0)

